# Delete query in Alasql

Tags: node.js, alasql

i am new to Alasql.

In my nodejs code i have written below piece of code for delete an item.  but it is not getting deleted.  Any help?

This is my create table query

```
 sqldb.exec('CREATE TABLE Cores ([node-id], name, [ip-address], [sw-version], longitude, latitude)');
```

here is the delete queries

```
sqldb.exec('DELETE FROM Cores WHERE [node-id] =\'%s\'', Id);
sqldb.exec('DELETE FROM Cores WHERE [node-id] = ?', Id);
sqldb.exec('DELETE FROM Cores WHERE [node-id] ='+ Id);
```

i tried all the above combinations when I return sqldb.exec(query)  i am getting 0 and the value is not getting deleted.  No error messages are thrown.

Comment: In what way are the above combinations not working? Are you getting error messages? Are they deleting zero rows when you expected them to delete more? Could you post your table structure? Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Robert. I have updated additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure we are using util module and I have used below code to format my query then it was able to delete a record.

```
var util = require('util');
sqldb.exec(util.format('DELETE FROM Cores WHERE [node-id] =\'%s\'', coreId));
```

Comment: You can avoid the util thing by using parameters for the SQL: `sqldb.exec("DELETE FROM Cores WHERE [node-id] =?", [coreId])`